# desktop application to work with mysql

Tags: mysql

I was wondering is there any Free Windows application that would allow to connect to a database hosted on the server and ability to edit its records, rows and tables all from the desktop.

Comment: Off topic and please try Google before posting a question like this. Look what i fouind by Googling for `desktop application to work with mysql`: http://sixrevisions.com/tools/applications_mysql_databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) is just one of them.

Comment: Thanks for Navicat suggestion looks like a great program for the job :)

Answer (score 1):

- [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) does the job for you pretty well
- <strike>[PHPMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) if you have a local webserver</strike>
- [Toad for MySQL](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) gives you partial success

Comment: PHPMyAdmin does not fit the "desktop application" requirement.